# Adding custom fields to a Drupal webform?

Tags: drupal, custom-fields

I'd like to create a survey via Drupal form asking supporters to note which issues they are most interested in.

We have set up a custom fields with this question and a list of assorted answers.

However, in Drupal, I see no way to add in my custom fields to the form.

What am I missing? Is there a different way to go about this?

Answer (score 3):

Click on the 'CiviCRM' tab in the webform.  Down the left side of this tab you'll see the contacts for the webform (Contact 1 etc). Matching each contact on the right side of the screen are all the fields for that contact, after you've selected the contact type.  You should be able to enable the custom field sets and other fields as well as groups, relationships etc - and then go on to enable the fields for the custom set.  If a custom field isn't showing up here, check that it's enabled in Civi.

Comment: NOTE: first step is you need to install/enable the webform_civicrm module - unclear from the Q if this has been done.